# Convert this particular .bash_profile to .zprofile

Tags: bash, osx, zsh, configuration, conversion

I have this .bash_profile:

```
alias ip='ipconfig getifaddr en0'

PS1="\[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] : "
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

and since MacOS updated to Catalina (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050) zsh become the default terminal.

How can I convert this to a zsh .zprofile?

Comment: What happens if you source this to your .zshrc ?

Comment: alias is working, but styling don't
as you can see in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050 we need some convertation

Answer (score 1):

The alias, the `-s` tests, the sourcing of other files using the dot command, and the `export` to create an environment variable are all the same across most current `sh`-like shells. These things work the same way in the `zsh` shell as in `bash`.

The `zsh` shell does not require you to double-quote all variable expansions, which means that you could remove a few double-quotes.

The `bash_completion` and `nvm.sh` scripts, if they are the same as the ones found in [the `nvm` Github repository](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), are written to support both the `bash` shell and the `zsh` shell, which means that we don't need to do anything special about these.

Moving on from these easy bits leaves one main issue, and that's the prompt string.

Your prompt string uses explicit color escape codes to display a red `$` followed by a space and the current working directory in green. Then there is a colon surrounded by spaces.  The current working directory is inserted into the prompt using `\w`, which is also affected by the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable in `bash`.  We're going to assume that `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` is unset.

Your prompt string in `bash`:

```bsh
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] : '
```

Your prompt string in `zsh` (without color):

```bsh
PS1='%# %~ : '
```

This prompt would show `#` in a root shell but `%` in a non-root shell. Would you want a `$` in place of `%` in non-root shells, use `%(!.#.$)` instead of `%#`. The prompt uses `%~` to include the current working directory, and you can add a number after the `%` to get the same effect as setting `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` in `bash`, so that `%2~` would include at most the two last pathname components of the current working directory's directory path.

Adding color to this:

```
PS1='%F{red}%#%f %F{green}%~%f : '
```

Read more about the prompt and how to set it in the `zshmisc` manual (search for the section entitled "EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES").

Bringing all this together, we end up with something like the following:

```bsh
alias ip='ipconfig getifaddr en0'

PS1='%F{red}%#%f %F{green}%~%f : '

export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm
[ -s $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh ] && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
[ -s $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ] && . $NVM_DIR/bash_completion
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of this can be copied across to your `.zprofile`.

Your colors can be set as explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Colors), for instance:

```
%B{red}%F{blue}$%f%b
```

creates a blue dollar sign.